# Woocommerce White page and fragments error {"fragments":{"div.widget_shopping_cart_content"

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce, cdn

We have a website built on woocommerce and we have customers reporting that they are getting a white page with just the below text, can you think what this might be?

{"fragments":{"div.widget_shopping_cart_content":"
\n\n
\n\n\t\n\t\t
No products in the basket.</li>\n\n\t\n</ul>\n\n\n</div>"},"cart_hash":""}

Comment: Further to this we believe it to be an issue with the CDN and JS as a solution we have only CDN'd the images, not quite a solution but get's rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Further to this we believe it to be an issue with the CDN and JS, as a solution we have only CDN'd the images, not quite a solution but get's rid of the error.